# Getting dimension of a line from purchline in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dimensions, dynamics-ax-2012

When I create a Purchase Order, and create Purchase Order lines associated with that purchase order, I can open up the Line details for the line, and then click the "Financial Dimensions" tab for the line and select a financial dimension to associate with the purchase order line.

Having done this, if I examine the database in SQL Server, I can see an entry in PURCHTABLE for my purchase order, and a corresponding line in the related table PURCHLINE which uses the PURCHID field to associate multiple PURCHLINE row's with one PURCHTABLE row.

However - although in the client, I can see the financial dimensions associated with my PURCHLINE, by looking in the line details section of the purchase order screen, I cannot find where this information is stored in the database to link it to my PURCHLINE row.

The PURCHLINE table has a LEDGERDIMENSION field which [from what I can determine by looking at the AOT] should associate it with a row in DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUECOMBINATION, however in all of the rows in PURCHLINE, the LEDGERDIMENSION field is set to 0.  The DEFAULTDIMENSION field in the PURCHLINE table has values, however the table to which it relates (DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUESET) has nothing but a HASH as its content - and no apparent relationships to any other table that would allow me to figure out what dimension it represents.

Does anyone know where in the database the data is stored that allows Dynamics AX to associate a set of financial dimension attributes to a Purchase Order line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thankyou Jan for your suggestions - they got me going in the right direction.  After reading through the whitepaper, based on the information [especially] on page 24, I was able to put together the following SQL which extracts the financial dimensions for a given purchase order with a single purchase order line.  It extracts the financial dimensions based on its purchase order number.  Note that you would still have to do more work if there was more than one line in the purchase order, to separate out the lines - but this code gets you a lot of the way there:

```
select
    ddv.DISPLAYVALUE,
    ddv.NAME 
from
    PURCHLINE pl
    inner join DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW ddv on (ddv.DEFAULTDIMENSION = pl.DEFAULTDIMENSION )
where
    pl.PURCHID = '<put purchase order number here>'
```

Fortunately, there is a view which does a lot of the work for you of navigating the rather complex table structures of the financial dimensions as they exist in the SQL server database associated with an installation of dynamics ax.

To separate out the financial dimensions for multiple lines in a given purchase order, the following sql does the job:

```
select
    ddv.DISPLAYVALUE,
    ddv.NAME,
    pl.LINENUMBER 
from
    PURCHLINE pl
    inner join DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW ddv on (ddv.DEFAULTDIMENSION = pl.DEFAULTDIMENSION )
where
    pl.PURCHID = '<put purchase order number here>'
order by
    pl.LINENUMBER, ddv.NAME
```

Comment: You should join on `DataAreaId` and `Partition` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The default dimensions of the purchase line is linked using the `DefaultDimension` field.
The `LedgerDimension` field links an account number, but that is normally not set.

The `DimensionAttributeValueSet` table also has a `RecId` field which is the interesting field. It is linked from the `DimensionAttributeValueSetItem` table and so on more complications.

To find out more about the new Dimension Framework in AX 2012 try reading the [whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E36B655-568E-4D4A-B161-152B28BAAF30/Implementing_the_Account_and_Financial_Dimensions_Framework_AX2012.pdf) about the new dimension framework.